# Cakephp cache not working using Cake2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

Currently i am using cake (2.0.3) cache is not working in the server and tried the ways are

1. permission to /app/tmp all the folders inside are world-writable (drwxrwxrwx)
2. Redoing the directory structure inside /app/tmp/cache

But this is not working. can any one help me?

Comment: "Not working" is what exactly?  Are there error messages?  How are you testing? Are you using debug=0?  (debug=1 will not create model cache files)

Comment: @del_dan Yes it was working locally but not works in server

Comment: @Costa I have tried all the debug=0,1,2 also there is response error

Comment: @Costa Cache only not righting to server (tmp folder)

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using **File storage engine** for cache you have to added some code on your controller to specified cache action.

class PagesController extends Controller{

var $cacheAction = array('/' =>cache_duration,'home' =>cache_duration,'downloads' =>cache_duration,'aboutus' =>cache_duration);

}

Here "cache_duration" is constant which should be declare on bootstrap.php file some like that define("cache_duration",'1 year',true);

On routes.php file insert following line of mapping.

Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'pages'));

Comment: You said regarding view cache (above the version 2) but its not working normal cache too .i need solution for the Persistence and model.